# Que signifie la construction « Car tout ainsi que » ?

Tags: grammaire, sens

Voici un extrait de L'Astrée de Honoré d'Urfé.

> Mais il lui advint lors comme à ces personnes qui ont longuement demeuré dans de profondes ténèbres, et qui sont tout à coup portées aux plus clairs rayons du Soleil: car tout ainsi qu'elles demeurent éblouies par trop de clarté, de même pour avoir trop de contentement, il n'en pouvait jouir d'un seul, les ayant eus tout à coup, et venant de quitter l'obscurité de ses déplaisirs.

Je ne comprends pas la construction « CAR tout … ses déplaisirs ». Comment est-elle formée ?

Comment: Cette demande contient deux questions. Il faudrait poser **une seule question** par demande. Et surtout **bien exposer sur quel point précis** porte les demandes. Il faut éviter les questions  sur le sens de phrases ou de texte qui ne peuvent conduire qu'à des réponses subjectives.

Comment: J'ai modifié la question en ne gardant que le premier point qui t'intéresse. Je t'invite à poser une nouvelle question, séparée, à propos du second point.

Answer (score 2):

Il faut comprendre « tout ainsi X, de même Y » comme « Y, de la même façon que X » dans cette phrase. Ce qui donne dans ce contexte : *Pour avoir¹ trop de contentement, de la même façon que ces personnes sorties des ténèbres demeurent éblouies par trop de clarté, il n'en pouvait jouir d'un seul, …*

C'est une tournure assez ancienne. Voir par exemple la section 1. 1. 1. de [cet article](https://journals.openedition.org/linx/625#tocto2n1).

—
 <sup>1. *Parce qu'il avait*.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Ce ne sont pas les ténèbres qui "demeurent éblouies par trop de clarté", mais les personnes qui ont longuement demeuré dans les ténèbres.

Au vu de la complexité de cet extrait, cela mériterait que tu y cites toute la page, pour bien comprendre le contexte.

Dans ce contexte, je verrais plus une signification dans le style : **"A l'image de"**.

De ce que j'ai compris, l'auteur fait un parallèle entre le personnage et les personnes qui ont longuement demeuré dans les ténèbres. 
Il fait alors le parallèle entre le fait qu'elles soit éblouies par trop de clarté, au fait que le personnage soit confronté à "trop" de contentement.

Le passage ***"les ayant eus tout à coup"*** fait référence à cette explosion de lumière qui frappe l'homme resté dans les ténèbres.